# Why Python multi-inherit not calling one parent

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

I'm just playing around Python MRO and found something weird for multi inherit. Code:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('enter A')
        print('leave A')


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('enter B')
        super().__init__()
        print('leave B')


class C():   
    def __init__(self):
        print('enter C')
        super().__init__()
        print('leave C')


class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        print('enter D')
        super().__init__()
        print('leave D')


print(D.__mro__)
d = D()
```

Result is:

```
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class 'object'>)
enter D
enter B
enter A
leave A
leave B
leave D
```

Class C was called, why "enter C" was not been printed?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, inheritance is just a way of saying "if you don't find such method in my class, search my parent class" with a search from left to right if we have multiple inheritance.

> For most purposes, in the simplest cases, you can think of the search
>   for attributes inherited from a parent class as depth-first,
>   left-to-right, not searching twice in the same class where there is an
>   overlap in the hierarchy. Thus, if an attribute is not found in
>   DerivedClassName, it is searched for in Base1, then (recursively) in
>   the base classes of Base1, and if it was not found there, it was
>   searched for in Base2, and so on.

[Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance)

TLDR; in class D, `super().__init__()` can be found in class B so Python doesn't search in class C